# SiriKit: shortcut defined in IntentsDefinition file not showing up in the Shortcuts app on macOS?

Tags: sirikit, sirishortcuts, intents-extension, macos-monterey

I haven't been able to add some basic SiriKit actions to my macOS app in macOS Monterey. To test this out, I created a new project, made it a macOS app with Storyboard. Then I added an intents definition file, and added a basic intent, with no inputs/outputs. I added the intent name to "Supported Intents" in the target "General" configuration.

When I build and run the app, the shortcut doesn't show up in the Apple Shortcuts app. I've tried looking for the "Siri" capability in "Signing & Capabilities" and it's not listed there (compared to a new iOS app where it would be).

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Would love some help.

BTW, I'm using Xcode 13.1 on macOS Monterey RC.

This is what my Custom Intent looks like.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am trying to locate that TestingSiriKitMac Xcode project, everything is iOS and I can't seem to convert it. any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem with our existing app. Deleting my app from my Mac (the current App Store version) and deleting the derived data in Xcode did the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But I was trying this on a brand-new project ... not one for an existing App Store app (though I need to do that in the future as well)

Comment: Actually think it might have been something to do with me using an incorrect name in the "Supported Intents" section. It seems to work now!

Comment: Deleting the App Store version was needed in my case.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I deleted the same production app in `/Applications`. Now it appears in the shortcuts app.